# ¿Porque no puedo acceder a los metodos de una biblioteca de clases?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

El programa de practica que estoy haciendo consiste en crear una baraja inglesa y escribir en consola las cartas (El rey de corazones -por ejemplo-), pero no salen en orden, sino al azar.
Tengo una biblioteca de clases con 2 clases y 2 enum para hacer este proyecto.
Pero al compilar el codigo del programa principal (imagen 1) me marca el error.
Apenas empiezo en esto, pero no logro entender el poque de este error

[image: Este es el codigo de la consola de aplicacion para ejecutarse]

Aqui esta el codigo de mi biblioteca de clases
[image: Biblioteca de clases-case carta]
.

```
class Deck
    {
        private Carta[] cartas;
        public Deck()
        {
            cartas = new Carta[52];
            for (int vPalo = 0; vPalo < 4; vPalo++)
            {
                for (int vRango = 0; vRango < 14; vRango++)
                {
                    cartas[vPalo * 13 + vRango - 1] = new Carta((Palo)vPalo, (Rango)vRango);
                }
            }
        }
        public Carta ObtenerCarta(int numeroCarta)
        {
            if (numeroCarta >=0 && numeroCarta <= 52)
            {
                return cartas[numeroCarta];
            }
            else
            {
                throw (new System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException("numeroCarta", numeroCarta, "El numero de cartas debe ser de 52!"));
            }
        }
        public void Shuffle()
        {
            Carta[] nuevoDeck = new Carta[52];
            bool[] asignado = new bool[52];
            Random source = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
            {
                int destCarta = 0;
                bool cartaEncontrada = false;
                while (cartaEncontrada == false)
                {
                    destCarta = source.Next(52);
                    if (asignado[destCarta] == false)
                    {
                        cartaEncontrada = true;
                    }
                }
                asignado[destCarta] = true;
                nuevoDeck[destCarta] = cartas[i];
            }
            nuevoDeck.CopyTo(cartas, 0);
        }
    }
class Carta
    {
        public readonly Palo palo;
        public readonly Rango rango;
        public Carta(Palo unPalo, Rango unRango)
        {
            palo = unPalo;
            rango = unRango;
        }
        private Carta()
        {

        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "El/La " + rango + " de " + palo;
        }
    }
```

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar el código en lugar de pantallazos por favor :D ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema se soluciona rápidamente, definitivamente todas las clases están como privadas.

Si agregas un `public` adelante, los problemas de compilación (que tenes hasta ahora, no revise todo el código) deberían solucionarse.

Tampoco analice si es lo que corresponde, solo me centre en tu error.

Comment: porque problablemente tengas cosas privadas a las que tratas de acceder desde afuera. y no agregues capturas, aclara el error, las capturas son dificiles de leer. yo pondria todo como publico, hasta que entiendas bien como funciona el tema de privado y publico

Comment: Ok ya lo tengo.  Ahora al ejecutar mi aplicacion de consola (No hay ningun error ya al compilar), me aparece que hay una excepcion sin controlar del tipo "System.IndexOutOfRangeException"

Comment: ok, para eso deberiamos ver donde la lanza para identificar el problema. Usualmente es una matriz a la que tratas de acceder a un elemento que no existe. como es otra pregunta, cierra esta pregunta, da una respuesta por aceptada, y en otra pregunta pon el codigo referido a eso.

Answer (score 0):

Por defecto las clases son Private, tenes que especificar que son clases publicas

Answer (score 0):

> class Deck

Las clases por defecto son privadas, lo que significa que sólo la clase podrá acceder a ellas, en cambio, si pones:

```
public class Deck
```

Significa que la clase es pública, por lo cual, **Cualquier otra clase puede utilizar sus métodos.**

Answer (score 0):

Hermano Recuerda que si quieres invocar una clase a una pagina , Tus Clases deben ser de tipo `Public` aparte deberas incluir a tu archivo esa clase y luego realizar al comienzo de tu codehebing

**Using ClaseQueHasCreado**

Si no le pones como publico nunca podra reconocer esa clase.

Saludos.